# Crash Handler in python

Tags: python, crash

I am working on a project, but I am running many processes, in which some are important function if they do not run then it may cause problems, So like I want a crash handler in my python program which will instantly detect crash of computer/python script. Is there any way to implement that, or any module.

***Thanks***

Comment: Have you tried `try` and `except`.

Comment: What kind of crash ? Exception, signals, shudown (lol) ?

Comment: shutdown or python script crash! @azro